# Java TCP synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, synchronized

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN9jk.jpg)

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pc99.jpg)

```
public void run () {
  try {
     handlers.addElement (this);
     broadcast("Welcome " + name);
     while(handlers.size() != 2){
         if(handlers.size() > 2){
             this.out.writeUTF ("The Room is full!");
             this.out.flush();
             handlers.removeElement(this);
             socket.close();
         }
     }
     broadcast("No of Player: " + handlers.size());
     for(int i = 0; i < handlers.size(); i++){
        GameHandler player = (GameHandler) handlers.get(i);
        broadcast("Player " + (i + 1) + ": " + player.name);
     }
     System.out.println("Game starts!");
     startGame(4);
     ....
}

protected static void broadcast (String message) {
  synchronized (handlers) {
     Enumeration e = handlers.elements ();
     while (e.hasMoreElements ()) {
        GameHandler handler = (GameHandler) e.nextElement ();
        try {
           handler.out.writeUTF (message);
           handler.out.flush ();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           handler.stop ();
        }
     }
  }
```

}

The problem is the difference between the expected result and my actual result.  I have no idea why the broadcast before the while loop runs normally but others run twice

Comment: Please provide the declaration of the variable handlers

Comment: handlers is a Vector which store (this)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in your case, each of the thread is sending the broadcast. Either you need to have a "master" / "server" of games thread that does the "system announcements" broadcasting, -or- elect one of the client threads (maybe the "player 1" thread?) to send the announcements.

Comment: but why does the first broadcast only do once?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is the difference between the expected result and my actual result. I have no idea why the broadcast before the while loop runs normally but others run twice

You really don't give enough details on your problem but I see these issues:

- You talk about TCP and the code mentions sockets but you are processing a local `elements` collection.  Unless you are talking to the same JVM over TCP (which is strange) the `elements` collection is going to start 2 players on each client.  Is that really what you expect?
- Even though you says `elements` is a `Vector` you still need to `synchronize` on it at the start of the `run()` method because you are performing multiple operations on it and there are race conditions.  For example, if 3 handlers are added, they will all remove themselves and close their own sockets.
- `Vector` really is an outdated collection.  You should be using something else.
- When the first thread adds itself to `elements` it then enters a spin loop waiting for the second person to join the game.  Seems like a waste there.  Some small `Thread.sleep(...)` would be appropriate.
- If the room is full I suspect that the thread should `return;` from the `run()` method.  Instead it continues on which I suspect is not good.

Hope something here helps.